# String not being added to URL String after being concatenated to call a GET Request

Tags: javascript, json, forms, xmlhttprequest

I am attempting to make a GET Request to some JSON data, the JSON data has ID's, I am attempting to specify which ID to retrieve in the URL, dependent on the input.value of a textfield with the use of a button and an onclick function.

I created a variable to store the input.value, and concatenated it into where my url is stored, then I call my GET Request.

But when I console.log(url), the output does not include the stored input.value even though when I console.log(id) it does appear.

Also, it does work if I fill id manually with the id instead of using input.value. But I need the user to decide on the front end which ID to select.

```
<input type="textarea">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
```

```
let id = '';
const url = 'https://www.someurl/' + id +  '?someurl.com';

function myFunction() {
const input = document.querySelector('input');
    id = input.value;
    console.log(id);
    console.log(url);
    const getXML = new XMLHttpRequest();
    getXML.responseType = 'json';
    getXML.open('GET', url);
    getXML.send();
    getXML.onreadystatechange = function () {
        const response = getXML.response;
        if (response) {
            console.log(getXML.status);
            console.log(response);
            console.log(id);
            console.log(url);
            console.log(typeof id);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `url` is declared when the `id` is `''` (`null`). Therefore even though it is added to the url, it is still empty. You need to set `url` as a variable, not a constant and after the value of `id` changes in `myFunction`, you need to update the `url`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <input type="textarea">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let id = '';
        function myFunction() {
            const input = document.querySelector('input');
            id = input.value;
            let url = 'https://www.someurl/' + id +  '?someurl.com';
            console.log(id);
            console.log(url);
            const getXML = new XMLHttpRequest();
            getXML.responseType = 'json';
            getXML.open('GET', url);
            getXML.send();
            getXML.onreadystatechange = function () {
                const response = getXML.response;
                if (response) {
                    console.log(getXML.status);
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log(id);
                    console.log(url);
                    console.log(typeof id);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead, try placing URL & ID inside the function

```
function myFunction() { 
const input = document.querySelector('input');
  let id = input.value;
  const url = 'https://www.someurl/' + id +  ' someurl.com';
    console.log(id);
    console.log(url);
    const getXML = new XMLHttpRequest();
    getXML.responseType = 'json';
    getXML.open('GET', url);
    getXML.send();
    getXML.onreadystatechange = function () {
        const response = getXML.response;
        if (response) {
            console.log(getXML.status);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please make your questions clear. See [ask].